# Pandas subtract columns not working with .iloc

Tags: pandas, indexing

I have a `dataframe`

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3], 'col2':['a','b','c']})

test
Out[79]: 
   col1 col2
0     1    a
1     2    b
2     3    c
```

I am trying to compute the "first difference" of `col1` explicitly using `iloc` but the results are nonsense:

```
test.iloc[1:,0] - test.iloc[:-1,0]
Out[80]: 
0    NaN
1    0.0
2    NaN
Name: col1, dtype: float64
```

I know I can use `pandas.DataFrame.diff` but I need to understand the machanics of `iloc` which is causing this to fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is with index values that are different between the two objects:

```
print (test.iloc[1:,0])
1    2
2    3
Name: col1, dtype: int64

print (test.iloc[:-1,0])

0    1
1    2
Name: col1, dtype: int64
```

Possible solution is create same index values:

```
a = test.iloc[1:,0].reset_index(drop=True) - test.iloc[:-1,0])
print (a)
0    1
1    1
Name: col1, dtype: int64
```

Or if length is always same convert one values to numpy array:

```
a = test.iloc[1:,0] - test.iloc[:-1,0].values
print (a)

1    1
2    1
Name: col1, dtype: int64
```